# Correct Installation of Google Analytics on Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, google-analytics, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a friend who has a developer working on this site: https://www.cannasaver.com/

When I access different pages on the site the UA code seems to duplicate over and over again according to the Google Tag Manager extension.

[image]

The developer is saying this is normal implementation and there there is nothing wrong. However on the other sites they own such as this: http://cannapages.com/ -- this does not seem to be the case.

I am wondering if the Google Analytics code is correctly implemented on https://www.cannasaver.com/ -- Any help you have as to if it is correctly added or what to do to fix it would be great appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

This is a common Google Tag Assistant behavior when encountering a single page website (SSA). The plugin cannot properly detect page-to-page transitions, for example asynchronously loaded in Ajax, as a result it will improperly report the GTM container loading for each new URL.

In reality, the snippet is only loaded once, from the debug we can see that a pageview is sent to each page visited and not all those that are written in the Tag Assistant (in the specific case the number of item in plugin increases by 1 for each page visited but it is only figurative).

Comment: Thank you for so much your response Michele! I guess I am just curious as to why it would happen on this site and no other sites we  have seen? Do you know why that might be happening uniquely to this site?

Also we are seeing odd things like 280 active users on the site but only like 20 active users in the active page area in Google Analytics. It almost seems as if Google is recording a bunch of new sessions when users go to new pages. 

Are you able to confirm that our coding is setup correct on our site? Any help or info you have is greatly appreciated! Thanks so much again!!!